# Pwinauto: How to start an application without GUI error

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

I am trying to open up a program with pywinauto then open a specific file in the program, but I am getting this error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1043, in app_idle
    h_process, int(timeout * 1000))

error: (1471, 'WaitForInputIdle', 'Unable to finish the requested operation because the specified process is not a GUI process.')
```

What is this error and how would I launch this application then click on File then open?

I have tried to add the timeout parameter, but I was not successful with that. Also I tried to connect to the app whenever it was already launched, and I wasn't able to connect when using the title. Here is my code:

```
import pywinauto

from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().start(r'c:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v191\CFX\bin\cfx5pre.exe', timeout=20)

app.CFX-Pre.menu_select("File->Open Case")
```

Comment: Probably you need rundll32.dll in the command line. Will check it later.

Comment: Well, maybe this app has console launcher that spawns child GUI process. Please try `.start(..., wait_for_idle=False)` and then `.connect(...)` to child process.

Comment: This worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this app has console launcher that spawns child GUI process. Please try `.start(..., wait_for_idle=False)` and then `.connect(...)` to child process.